# getImageData doesn't read right values & putImageData doesn't update the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having a problem with updating the canvas. The code is hosted at http://ssarangi.github.com/nombre/. The problem is I am loading a red image and after the loading is done I convert the image to Yellow and want to re-render it to the canvas.

```
// Turn to Yellow
function updateImage() {
   // Update the image
    var ctx = canvas2d.getContext("2d");
    var width = canvas2d.width;
    var height = canvas2d.height;
    var pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

    for (var x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            var offset = (y * width + x) * 4;
            pixels.data[offset] = 0;
            pixels.data[offset+1] = 255;
            pixels.data[offset+2] = 255;
            pixels.data[offset+3] = 255;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(pixels, 0, 0);
}
```

However, the ctx doesn't update the pixels. However, doing the same thing on a simple html page did work for me. This example enables WebGL though. Could someone point me to the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: Your link gives a 403 Forbidden. Please edit your question with the correct URL, or put your code in a JSFiddle.

Comment: That's strange. I can access it from multiple machines. Even from my phone..

Comment: https://github.com/ssarangi/nombre - Hopefully you can see the problem from here too.

Comment: http://ssarangi.github.com/nombre/ - This should now work too.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with the code provided, except that it claims to make yellow pixels when it in fact makes teal pixels. Here it is modified and working, making yellow pixels:

http://jsfiddle.net/TCf6f/

---

The code on your webpage works when you set a breakpoint in the chrome debugger, specifically it turns the canvas teal as your code specifies. It does not seem to work when there isn't a breakpoint, and I imagine the size of the CanvasPixelArray is to blame. What happens with a smaller canvas?

Whats weirder, sometimes you can set a breakpoint and see the operation partially working, like here:

[image]

With earlier breakpoints lead to the entire thing being the correct teal.

If a smaller canvas works, try modifying the pixel array in 4 or 8 chunks and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Simon.. You are right. Putting a breakpoint does partially update the buffer. However, this works only on chrome right now. Doing the same thing on firefox didn't work for me. I am guessing webgl is somehow interfering with this. I created a separate canvas object which just worked fine with this.